Java Streams - convert a list to a Map of Object with a List
I'm trying to convert a List into a Map of Objects where that Objects holds the List.
Consider the following classes:
class A {
  String code;  
}

class B {
  A a;
  String value;
}

AB {
  A a;
  List<B> bList;
}

I have a List<B> sourceList  that I want to convert into a Map<String, AB> targetMap
If we have the following data for sourceList:
[
  {
     value = "foo",
     a = {code = "code1"}
  },
  {
     value = "bar"
     a = {code = "code1"}
  {
     value = "hello"
     a = {code = "code2"}
  }
]

The targetMap should look like this:
{
  "code1" =
  {
     a = {code = "code1"}
     bList =
     [
       {
         value = "foo",
         a = {code = "code1"}
       },
       {
         value = "bar",
         a = {code = "code1"}
       }
     ]
  },

  "code2" =
  {
    a = {code = "code2"}
    bList =
    [
      {
        value = "hello"
        a = {code = "code2"}
      }
    ]
  }
}

How can I do this?
I tried using the Collectors.groupingBy and Collectors.mapping but both looks like only results in a Map of a Collection.

How about good old for loop?

Yes, that's possible. But I had a gut feeling that it was possible with streams, I just can't figure out how to do it. And thanks to the answers below, I was looking at the wrong Collectors methods.
Using the Collectors.collectingAndThen worked! Thanks for that. I chose the answer by @Sweeper as it was the first one posted.

Use groupingBy to group by getA().getCode() as usual. In the downstream, use Collectors.toList, similar to what the one-argument groupingBy collector does, but then, convert that List<B> into an AB using collectingAndThen.
Map<String, AB> convert(List<B> list) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            x -> x.getA().getCode(),
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toList(),
                    // assuming AB has a constructor that takes an A and a List<B>
                    bs -> new AB(bs.get(0).getA(), bs)
            )
    ));
}

Since groupingBy does not create empty groups, bs is always non-empty, so it is safe to do bs.get(0).

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class A {
    String code;
    
    public A(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}

class B {
    A a;
    String value;
    
    public B(A a, String value) {
        this.a = a;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class AB {
    A a;
    List<B> bList;
    
    public AB(A a, List<B> bList) {
        this.a = a;
        this.bList = bList;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public List<B> getBList() {
        return bList;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<B> sourceList = Arrays.asList(
            new B(new A("code1"), "foo"),
            new B(new A("code1"), "bar"),
            new B(new A("code2"), "hello")
        );
        
        Map<String, AB> targetMap = sourceList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                b -> b.getA().getCode(),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toList(),
                    bList -> new AB(bList.get(0).getA(), bList)
                )
            ));
        
        // Printing the result
        targetMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
            System.out.println("Key: " + key);
            System.out.println("A: " + value.getA().getCode());
            System.out.println("BList:");
            value.getBList().forEach(b -> {
                System.out.println("  Value: " + b.getValue() + ", A: " + b.getA().getCode());
            });
        });
    }
}

The sourceList is converted into targetMap using Java streams and the Collectors.groupingBy method.
The Collectors.collectingAndThen method is used to transform the grouped result into an AB object.

You can customize using the downstream reduction function of Collectors.groupingBy.
Try it like this
Map<String, AB> targetMap = sourceList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                b -> b.a.code, // Group by the code
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toList(),
                        bList -> new AB(bList.get(0).a, bList))));

The whole code sample
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MockTest {
    class A {
        String code;

        A(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        // getters, setters, equals, and hashCode methods
    }

    class B {
        A a;
        String value;

        B(A a, String value) {
            this.a = a;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    class AB {
        A a;
        List<B> bList;

        AB(A a, List<B> bList) {
            this.a = a;
            this.bList = bList;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testClass() {
        List<B> sourceList = Arrays.asList(
                new B(new A("code1"), "foo"),
                new B(new A("code1"), "bar"),
                new B(new A("code2"), "hello"));

        Map<String, AB> targetMap = sourceList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        b -> b.a.code, // Group by the code
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                Collectors.toList(),
                                bList -> new AB(bList.get(0).a, bList))));

        // Print the targetMap to verify the result
        targetMap.forEach((code, ab) -> {
            System.out.println("code: " + code);
            System.out.println("a: " + ab.a.code);
            System.out.println("bList: ");
            ab.bList.forEach(b -> System.out.println("  value: " + b.value + ", code: " + b.a.code));
            System.out.println();
        });
    }
}

Print output is:
code: code2
a: code2
bList: 
  value: hello, code: code2

code: code1
a: code1
bList: 
  value: foo, code: code1
  value: bar, code: code1


I understand that the topic concerns streams, but occasionally it can be challenging to utilize a stream to assemble such an object. Because of  simplicity, I would recommend writing a for loop instead, since it is simpler to write and read and in certain cases, it could have fewer bugs.
List<B> sourceList = Arrays.asList(
        new B(new A("code1"), "foo"),
        new B(new A("code1"), "bar"),
        new B(new A("code2"), "hello")
);
// change to Map<String, AB>
Map<String, AB> targetMap = new HashMap<>();
for (B b : sourceList) {
    String key = b.getA().getCode();
    if (targetMap.containsKey(key)) {
        targetMap.get(key).getBList().add(b);
    } else {
        targetMap.put(key, new AB(b.getA(), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(b))));
    }
}


Oh for-loops can definitely solve this. It was just my curiosity that I wanted to figure out how to do it in streams.
